# Manipulating JSON Array PHP - Find Value in array

Tags: php, arrays, json, data-manipulation

I have a JSON array that comes in via API. I am looking to print out the data however the values that are returned are not always in the same place for each of the items. Below is an example of the JSON that is return - This is only one part of the JSON, it is a large file:

```
"standardSpecification": [
    {
       "Technical": [
            {
                "id": 13501,
                "name": "Performance",
                "description": "XXXXX",
                "value": "standard",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 13502,
                        "name": "maximum speed (km/h)",
                        "value": 169
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 13503,
                        "name": "acceleration 0-62mph (s)",
                        "value": 12.2
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 113502,
                        "name": "maximum speed (mph)",
                        "value": 105
                    }
                ]
            },
```

I am unable to use things like, to manipulate it because for one item it maybe correct and not for another:

```
echo $tech_array['standardSpecification'][5]['Technical'][11]['items'][8]['value'];
```

Is there a way to find "Performance" and then print out all the items related to that? I know i can use in_array() and array_search() however I can not work out how to return the items.

It maybe an easy solution, so am hoping someone can help *fingers crossed*.

Comment: the values you are searching for is always in the same array level?

Comment: Hello Hassan, Unfortunately they sit at different levels, but are say under the main heading of `"Technical"` each time. And sometimes they are not there. It just depends on what the API returns.

Comment: well, the posted answer seems applicable, but you will need to check for the existence of the `Performance` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will do what you want. It has a small recursive function which searches into the array for an object with a property `name` = `Performance` and returns that node. You can then simply extract the `items` property from that node.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
// look for the array element which is 'name' => 'Performance'
function search($arr, $key, $value) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            if (($a = search($v, $key, $value)) !== false) 
                return $a;
            continue;
        }
        if ($k == $key && $v == $value) return $arr;
    }
    // not found, return false
    return false;
}

if (($node = search($arr, 'name', 'Performance')) !== false) {
    $items = $node['items'];
    print_r($items);
}
```

Output for the sample data you provided:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13502
            [name] => maximum speed (km/h)
            [value] => 169
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13503
            [name] => acceleration 0-62mph (s)
            [value] => 12.2
        )  
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 113502
            [name] => maximum speed (mph)
            [value] => 105
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nick. This is exactly what I am looking for. I can then use this to find over elements of the array by changing `search($arr, 'name', 'Performance')` to say `search($tech_array, 'name', 'Fuel consumption')` which will return them values! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, give the below code a try:

```
<?php
$json = "";//you json api response
$jsonArray = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($jsonArray['standardSpecification'] as $spec){
   foreach($spec['Technical'] as $technical){
      echo "Performance: ".$technical['name'];
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: don't hesitate to ask, tell me